# Closing specific window, but not app in tray

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to close a window but not app it self (it is running in tray)

There app I need to minimize to tray but there no option to do it in app settings. So I was trying to write bat script to to that.

I got this so far:

```
:: open app
START C:\"Program Files (x86)"\APP_NAME\APP_NAME.exe
:: close window but not app (doesn't work, kills entire app)
taskkill /fi "windowtitle eq APP_NAME"
```

Comment: A Windows app can't run without a main window unless it's been specifically coded to run that way.  What you're seeing is perfectly normal.

Comment: If you have the window handle you might be able to send it a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) message with a `SC_MINIMIZE` parameter, but I don't know if there's an existing utility to do that.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't really know what you mean by "Windows app", I meant just an app what runs on win10, I also do understand it's "normal", I just provided a code I have from other scrips. What I'm trying to do is instead of manually clicking "X" on app window is to do it with script

Comment: Try `start "" /min "%programfiles(x86)%\APP_NAME\APP_NAME.exe"` with the double quotes before `/min`

Comment: @Gerhard doesn't work either, I tested it with with other app which runs in tray too "sharex" - same issue. Tried to do that with notepad and it minimizing window but that's not what I need (obviously noteped doesn't run in tray to begin with), I want to minimize app to tray not taskbar, thanks for trying to help nevertheless

Comment: Why are you trying to close it using its Window Title? and how do you know what that is? What is wrong with trying to close it using its Image Name instead? `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im APP_NAME.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nircmd.exe hide in order to hide the desired window. See the following two pages:

1. [NirCmd - Windows command line tool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
2. [NirCmd Command Reference - win](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/win.html)

Comment: Thanks! Had to add `ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 > nul` to sleep for 5 seconds to wait until app actually launch and window is shown

Comment: or `timeout /T 5` instead of ping thing